# Is Plotly Dash Enterprise a viable alternative to React for a non-data visualization web app? What are its drawbacks?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, plotly-dash, web-deployment-project

What are the cons of using **Plotly Dash Enterprise** for building general purpose web applications? Is it better than **React**? I guess the development time will be less when using Plotly Dash, but it may also not be scalable.

Has anyone done this or anything similar?

I am working on developing an internal web application which will ultimately be used by over 10000 people. The application is not complex but it’s not related to dashboard/data visualization.

I am trying to decide between React and Dash.

Comment: I also have the same question and case with you, and none of them explained or made an article about this. I also think about mounting the Dash with Python API framework like FastAPI to address unscalable websites